# Dynamically changing height of plotly shiny graph leads to overlapping with other uiobjects

Tags: r, shiny, ggplotly

I have a shiny app with 2 graphs. The first (Plot 1) has a varying number of subplots depending on a dropdown. To keep the graph legible I need to adjust the height of the graph as a function of the number of subplots. When I increase the height of the plot, it starts to overlap the plot below (Plot 2) and sits on top of the "Plot 2" heading and disappears behind the plot below. Is there a way I can resize Plot 1 and move the rest of the elements down to accommodate it? Reprex below:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

ui_page <- function(){
  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      selectizeInput(inputId = "num_panels",
                     label = "Select Number of Subplots:",
                     choices = c(1,2,3),
                     selected = 1)
    ),
    
    h1("Plot 1"),
    plotlyOutput("plot_1"), 
    
    h1("Plot 2"),
    plotlyOutput("plot_2"),
  )
}

server_page <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  #Create Plot 1
  output$plot_1 <- renderPlotly({
    
    # Modify the dataset dependign on teh number of subplots needed
    num_panel <- as.numeric(input$num_panels)
    locs <- c("Place 1", "Place 2", "Place 3")
    df1 <- c()
    for (ii in 1:num_panel) {
      df1[[ii]] <- data.frame(location_name=locs[ii],time=c(1,2,3,4), yy=c(10,20,30,40))
    }
    df <- bind_rows(df1)
    
    TS_plot <-  ggplot(df, aes_string(x = "time", y = "yy")) +
      geom_point() +
      facet_wrap(~location_name, ncol = 1)

    fig <- ggplotly(TS_plot, height = 300*num_panel) 
  })
  
  # Create Plot 2
  output$plot_2 <- renderPlotly({
    fig <- plot_ly(
      x = c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys"),
      y = c(20, 14, 23),
      name = "SF Zoo",
      type = "bar",
      height = 300)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui_page, server=server_page)
```

Looks good with 1 subplot:

[image]

More subplots and it starts to overlap:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

ui_page <- function(){
  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      selectizeInput(inputId = "num_panels",
                     label = "Select Number of Subplots:",
                     choices = c(1,2,3),
                     selected = 1)
    ),
    
    h1("Plot 1"), 
    uiOutput("p1"),
    
    h1("Plot 2"),
    plotlyOutput("plot_2")
  )
}

server_page <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  ht <- reactive(300*as.numeric(input$num_panels))
  
  fig1 <- eventReactive(input$num_panels, {
    # Modify the dataset dependign on teh number of subplots needed
    num_panel <- as.numeric(input$num_panels)
    locs <- c("Place 1", "Place 2", "Place 3")
    df1 <- c()
    for (ii in 1:num_panel) {
      df1[[ii]] <- data.frame(location_name=locs[ii],time=c(1,2,3,4), yy=c(10,20,30,40))
    }
    df <- bind_rows(df1)
    
    TS_plot <-  ggplot(df, aes_string(x = "time", y = "yy")) +
      geom_point() +
      facet_wrap(~location_name, ncol = 1)
    
    ggplotly(TS_plot, height = 300*num_panel) 
  })
  
  #Create Plot 1
  output$plot_1 <- renderPlotly({
    fig1()
  })
  
  output$p1 <- renderUI({
    plotlyOutput("plot_1", height=ht())
  })
  
  fig2 <-  plot_ly(
      x = c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys"),
      y = c(20, 14, 23),
      name = "SF Zoo",
      type = "bar",
      height = 300)
  
  # Create Plot 2
  output$plot_2 <- renderPlotly({
    fig2
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui_page, server=server_page)
```

Comment: Given the length of the code, elaborating a little on what the essence of the solution is and why it helps would be fantastic in order to understand what is especially relevant and why the solution works.